# Django - how to pass filtered querysets to Detailview

Tags: python, django

I have Client, servers, users models. In the Client Detailview i would like to display the servers and users that belong to that company. How do I filter that?

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name="Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

**views.py**

```
class clientdetails(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
template_name = 'myapp/clientdetails.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Client.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(clientdetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['servers'] = Server.objects.filter(** servers belonging to that client **)
    context['users'] = User.objects.filter(** servers belonging to that client **)
    return context
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to be a general use case i.e all objects retrieved from the server need to be for a specific client. You can take a look at using [limit-choices-to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

```
class ClientDetails(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'myapp/clientdetails.html'
    model = Client

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        client = self.object
        context = super(ClientDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['servers'] = Server.objects.filter(company=client)
        context['users'] = User.objects.filter(company=client)
        return context
```

OR using the related names

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['servers'] = self.object.server_set.all()
        context['users'] = self.object.user_set.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do this in the view at all; you can follow the relationships in the template.

```
{{ object.name }}
{% for server in object.server_set.all %}
    {{ server.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% for user in object.user_set.all %}
    {{ user.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can remove your get_context_data method altogether.

Comment: thanks you. I haven't tested this but this is a good idea. but I prefer to do it in the view and keep the templates "simple".